# Building a hierarchical tree with a single SQL query

Tags: sql, database, hierarchical-data

I have a **SQL** table with the following structure.

```
id   - int
par  - int (relational to id)
name - varchar
```

Column **par** contains references to **id** or *NULL* if no reference, this table is meant to build an hierarchical tree.

Then, given the data:

```
id par  name

1  NULL John
2  NULL Mario
3  1    George
4  3    Alfred
5  4    Nicole
6  2    Margaret
```

I want to retrieve a hierarchical tree, up to the last parent, from a given single **id**.

Example, I want to know the tree from **Nicole** to the last parent. So the query result will be:

```
id par  name

5  4    Nicole
4  3    Alfred
3  1    George
1  NULL John
```

I would normally do this with a SQL query repeating over and over and building the tree server side but I do not want that now.

Is there any way to achieve this with a single SQL query?
I need this for either MySQL or PgSQL.

And I want to know also, if possible, is it also widely supported? In which versions of either MySQL or PgSQL can I expect support?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible with a single query in Postgres using a recursive common table expression. This is not possible in MySQL as it is one of the few database to not support recursive CTEs.

It would look something like this (not tested)

```
WITH RECURSIVE tree (id, par, name) AS (
    SELECT id, par, name 
    FROM the_table
    WHERE name = 'Nicole'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT id, par, name 
    FROM the_table tt
      JOIN tree tr ON tr.id = tt.par
)
SELECT *
FROM tree
```

Comment: MySQL 8 supports recursive cte, might worth taking a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Answer (score 1):

For Postgres, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html

MySQL doesn't support this syntax (unless it's in a beta/development tree somewhere). Oracle has something similar using `connect by prior`.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, this is done via:

```
SELECT [[LEVEL,]] id, par, name FROM my_table
 START WITH name = 'Nicole'
CONNECT BY [[NOCYCLE]] id = PRIOR par
[[ORDER SIBLINGS BY name ASC]]
```

(my `[[…]]` syntax denotes optional query bits.

MySQL is planning to integrate such a feature. For PostgreSQL there is another answer helping you.

Comment: Interesting that MySQL is planning that as well. Do you have any reference or timelines for this?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I have probably been fooled by [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/fr/todo-future.html) because nothing in English is available on the matter.