# SQL hierarchical tree, sum of children and parents

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a data table something along the lines of

[image: table]

The parentID is the schoolId of the parent. I work with MySQL 8.0.

I followed [Building a hierarchical tree with a single SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7259829/building-a-hierarchical-tree-with-a-single-sql-query), this question doesn't sum the values of the children and the parents. The most questions i find online are about the sum of the children and not the parents and the children. I tried it with a declare table and then adding  the data to the table. Is there a way to do this with just sql? I don't have much experience with sql.

I want to get something along the lines of

[image: wanted]

For now it work with just counting the sum of the children.
This is something like this

```
SELECT 
            id,
            parentId,
            year, 
            amountStudents,
            name
            ISNULL(( select sum(amountStudents) from School sibiling with (nolock)
                inner join School parent with (nolock) on parentId = sibling.parentId
                as SchoolbestuurOmzet
            FROM School.
```

This code might not work because i stripped some code from it.
The basic concept was i compare the elements to see if they are sibling

Now i'm trying to it with something like this

```
DECLARE @result TABLE(
        id int NOT NULL,
        parentID int NULL,
        parentName varchar(100) NULL,
        year int NULL,
        name varchar(100) NULL,
        amountStudents int NULL,
        totalAmount int NULL
);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which database system do you use?

Comment: I will update it

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)